# How does Java add variables to annotations

Tags: java, shiro

The requirepermissions in each controller method is inconsistent with the required permissions path.  Is it possible to use Aspect to obtain the name of the class object, complete the permissions path, and verify the permissions [see code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sefgH.jpg)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method - RequestMethod.POST) 
@RequiresPermissions("sys:" + getNameT(clazz) + "：delete")
public BaseResult<?> delete(String[] ids) {
    try {
        return baseservice.delete(ids);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return BaseResult.fail(); 
   }
}

public static String getNameT(Class<?> cls){
    return cls.getSimpleName().toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Not possible (AFAIK), make your own annotation extending RequiresPermisssions with Class and string "delete" as parameter.

Comment: The question is interesting but could use some better formulation. As far as I understand, you want subclasses that have different values for your annotation?

Comment: I found some Shiro AOP juggling magic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743749/shiro-authorization-permission-check-using-annotation-not-working

Comment: Annotation parameters should only be static

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the default [WildcardPermission class](https://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authz/permission/WildcardPermission.html),
you can just ig[nore the case of your class name](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/1.8.x/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/authz/permission/WildcardPermission.java#L158).